# "Save Tag Edits" が翻訳対象になっていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

質問のタグだけを編集しようとしたときに、編集を保存するボタンとして "Save Tag Edits" と書かれたボタンが出るようになっていました。この文を翻訳しようと思ったのですが、対応しそうな string が Traducir で見つかりませんでした。翻訳対象への追加が漏れているかもしれません。

https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Save.*Tag.*Edits

[image]

Comment: MSE での関連しそうな投稿: ["Save Tag Edits" translation not used anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370052)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2021-11-02 現在、以下の通り翻訳が適用されているようです。
コメント欄に書いた [MSE の関連投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370052) も [status-completed] になっていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]